# How to fetch data from different tables in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am new to Django and Python,

I have a table for clients, and one for trips. I can display the clients on the clients page, and the same for the trips.

But on the clients page, I want to show all the trips that are linked to each client. And this is where I hit a wall.

This is my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


# Create your models here.

class Clientes(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    apelido = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    morada = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=9, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])
    nif = models.CharField(max_length=9, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.nome, self.apelido)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Clientes"

class Viagem(models.Model):
    trip_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Clientes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comp = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    data = models.DateField()
    destino = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.trip_id

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Viagens"
```

This is my **views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Clientes, Viagem

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    ls= Clientes.objects.all()    
    context = {'ls': ls}
    return render(request, "booking/home.html", context)

def cliente(request, id):
    ls= Clientes.objects.filter(id=id)
    context = {'ls': ls}
    return render(request, "booking/cliente.html", context)

def trip(request):
    ls= Viagem.objects.all()    
    context = {'ls': ls}
    return render(request, "booking/trip.html", context)
```

and this is the table on the **home.html**

```
    <table id="selector" class="table is-fullwidth is-hoverable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Apelido</th>
        <th>Morada</th>
        <th>Telemóvel</th>
        <th>NIF</th>
        <th>Viagens</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for ls in ls %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ls.nome}}</td>
        <td>{{ls.apelido}}</td>
        <td>{{ls.morada}}</td>
        <td>{{ls.tel}}</td>
        <td>{{ls.nif}}</td>
        <td>{{ls.trip_id}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %} 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I assume it has something to do with ForeignKey, but a ForeignKey on the first class won't work.

I thought about creating a new `def` on the `views.py` using the `Viagem` table and a diferent context, but that also doesn't seem to be the solution.

So, anyone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your *views.py*, specifically the `cliente` function, you want to add the following line:

```
viagems=Viabem.objects.filter(cliente=ls)
```

modify the following line:

```
ls= Clientes.objects.filter(id=id)
```

so that it now shows:

```
ls=Clientes.objects.get(id=id)
```

and then change your context to equal:

```
context = {'ls': ls, 'viagems': viagems}
```

then you will be able to iterate over the different viagems in your html template file with the following kind of structure:

```
{% for viagem in viagems %}
  {{ viagem.whatever_field }}
{% endfor %}
```

and that should be it, I believe...

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but it still returns empty. On the `clientes.html` page, I have a table with all clients, and at the end a field where I want to output their `viagem.trip_id`.

Comment: Well I did have a clarification, first of all.  In the first line where I typed _Viabem_ it should (obviously) be _Viagem_.  If you're still having the problem after that I would look into whether or not you have any trips that correspond to the cliente ID.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it before trying. No luck. And yes, there are trips corresponding to the client, I can query it on the shell.

Comment: I'm really not sure what to tell you at this point.  The code there, as well as the code in the other example here by @Charnel should, presumably, work without issues so long as the database contains the appropriate records...  Maybe if I get a chance today I can rewrite everything with catches in case the database is structured wrong and see what that gives you as output, but I'm not sure if that's going to happen or not.  I'll try to make time for it here.

If you could post your database queries here so I could see all fields of the applicable records it would help, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are filtering by ID (fetching single object), this is one of the options to go:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def cliente(request, id):
    ls = get_object_or_404(Clientes, id=id)
    trips = obj.viagem_set.all()
    context = {'ls': ls, 'trips': trips}
    return render(request, "booking/cliente.html", context)
```

**template.html**

```
<table id="selector" class="table is-fullwidth is-hoverable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Apelido</th>
    <th>Morada</th>
    <th>Telemóvel</th>
    <th>NIF</th>
    <th>Viagens</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ls.nome}}</td>
    <td>{{ls.apelido}}</td>
    <td>{{ls.morada}}</td>
    <td>{{ls.tel}}</td>
    <td>{{ls.nif}}</td>
    <td>{% for trip in trips %}{{ trip.id }}{% endfor %}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %} 
</tbody>
```

While I'm not sure why you need to show record ID's in the table.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but it still retuns empty. On the `clientes.html` page, I have a table with all clients, and at the end a field where I want to output their `trip_id`. I also have a page displaying all trips, and I can output the client name, via the ForeignKey.

Comment: @JoãodeSousa are you sure there are related trips? Can you run it in debug to see 
 `trips` actually populated?

Comment: yes there are. I have a page, `trips.html`, where I display all trips on database.

Comment: I just noticed your comment about why showing the record id. It's not the record id, it's an ID created by the user, like a "trip name". The goal is that when looking at the clients table, there is the information about the trip_id, that is also a link to the trip info page.

Comment: ok, can you post an example of populated `trips` variable? Use breakpoint in debug with evaluating value or use a django shell with running queries with some of the client ID's you are using...or simply put `print(trips)` and post whatever it prints here.

Comment: `Viagem.objects.all()
(Pdb) <QuerySet [<Viagem: 12B>, <Viagem: 13D>]>`

Comment: And what the output will be in this case: `Viagem.objects.all().values_list('id', 'cliente_id')` ?

Comment: `(Pdb) Viagem.objects.all().values_list('id', 'cliente_id')
<QuerySet [(1, 1), (2, 2)]>`

Answer (score 0):

@João de Sousa, I found you want to show all trips that are associated with each client.

First of all you have to get a single client by his id `obj = clients.objects.get(id = id)` then this id pass to referred model like this `obj1 = Viagem.objects.filter( id = obj.id)`

According to my understanding from your above posted question is that you want to get help about how you get data from reference model/table. Django provides very easy and flexible way to get data from tables.

Feel free to ask any question if you need more clarification.